# why so many languages that compile to JS

Tags: javascript

There is a huge list of languages that compile to JS
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

the question is: why? for what purpose? 
just to avoid programming in pure JavaScript

Comment: It's the only way to provide a language alternative for front-end web development.

Comment: thx! I just surprised that no big efforts to replace/fix JavaScript itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are javascript interpreters on nearly every consumer device/computer/browser out there. If you make a new language, you normally have to compile it to machine code or ensure that users have your language runtime installed.

Compile-to-JS languages sidestep this by compiling down to a language that already has the capability of running on billions of machines. This means that day-one someone can code in your language, and have it runnable almost anywhere.

Comment: Thx for answer! But what I can't understand - why such companies like Mozilla, Opera etc do not move forward this "day-one"

For example why such language like ClojureScript could not replace JS ?

Comment: They could, if enough people adopted them -- but Mozilla and Apple and Google all have different goals, and aligning on supporting a new native language. But even if they all agreed, all the old browsers would not support them, so your install base of the new language would not be near 100% (like JS is). Compiling to JS means that your new code will work on legacy browsers and machines.

Comment: look forward to changing developers' mind in this question in web 3.0